# Linear Regression with multiple categorical values

Tags: r, regression, lm, linear

I am trying to build a regression model using R where,

**reponse variable:**

- price (continuous)

**explanatory variables:**

- Age,accumulated kilometers,weight,horsepower,cylinder 
  volume, tax (continuous)
- Metallic color,ABS,Airbag,CD_Player,Power steering, Metallic_Rim  (categorical - binary)
- Color (Categorical - 5 levels)
- Fuel Type (Categorical - 3 levels)

How can I detect the variables that should be used in my linear model in one step.
I know that binary variables influence on response variable can be checked using T-test.
How can I check which all of these variables(continous, categorigal-binary, categorical-multiple levels) influnece my response variable price in one step ??

Comment: If by one step your implying a shortcut to identifying significant variables automatically it would not be advised.

Answer (score 1):

The statistical value that you obtain is the univariate significance test. You may want to check the *joint* significance of your variables. Say that you have a binary variables for each color. You want to test the joint significance of the four variables `color` (you omit one color because it becomes your referent class) via a F-test.

Related to the previous point, you definitely *should* use binary variables for each color and Fuel type because colors will be coded as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 = Red, Green, Blue, Black, White. If you include the variable `color` as it is, the statistical software will not understand that you use a label, but rather an actual value. In other words, the program will understand it as: "going from Red(1) to Blue(2) increases the price of the car by USDxx." To understand my point, if you code the colors differently: Red=3, Blue=1, Green=4, Black=2, White=5, the coefficient in front of `color` will change, indicating that the information contained in `color` has changed, which should not be the case.

Another way of seeing this is that you cannot take the first derivative of a Red or a Blue car. Think in terms of computer language and not how you interpret the numbers, a computer has no brain.

For a more elaborate answer on the univariate/multivariate significance test, see [this post.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/182554/32279)

Answer (score 0):

The significance value should be displayed next to the variable in the model, whichever value is significant influences your DV. Look [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/rreg.htm) or alternatively use the install.packages("Swirl") and do the regression package and this will explain everything.